# Converting from DateTime to string in Julia

Tags: string, datetime, julia

Is there any user-friendly and efficient function to convert from a DateTime into a string? I'm thinking of something that would look like `string(mydate, mydateformat)`, used for instance with `mydate = Dates.now()` and `mydateformat = Dates.DateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd H:M:S")`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Thanks for asking this question; I realized I forgot to document the important `Dates.format(dt::TimeType, df::DateFormat)` function!

The usage is pretty much what you're looking for:

```
julia> dt = DateTime(2015,7,15,3,2)
2015-07-15T03:02:00

julia> Dates.format(dt, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS")
"2015-07-15 03:02:00"
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! Now would it be too much to ask for `Dates.now()` to  return milliseconds as well? ;) (I know I can use `time()` to get them, but I'm lazy!)

Comment: Is there a quick trick to get the UTC time instead of the local time?